# How to find, properly configure MS Team Foundation server?

Tags: postgresql, tfs, port

I have a win7 virtual machine, that has a postgresql installed. There is an (apache) Enterprise DB on my localhost:8080.

I have installed MS Team Foundation Server successfully, and I can see from the management console, that my "DefaultCollection" is online.

Browsing for localhost:8080/tfs or localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection returns a 404 not found error. I had no say on what port I would like to use,

Can you help me find the proper address for this team foundation server? Or tell me how to configure it properly. (I am unfamiliar with this server configuring world, please provide detailed commands or material.)

Comment: "Apache EnterpriseDB"? *blink* *blink*. Um. What? Did you install some kind of bundle? From where?

What does MS Team Foundation have to do with PostgreSQL? Doesn't it require MS SQL Server or Jet or similar?

Comment: Heh. The root of the porblem is they sit on the same port, and I don't know how to configure the team foundation server.

Comment: You've provided nowhere near enough information for someone to help you. Right now it looks like this has nothing to do with PostgreSQL. Again: What's "Apache PostgreSQL"? Is it some kind of bundle? Where did you get it from? **DETAILS** please.

Comment: It is postgresql for windows bundled with this: http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/
It has nothing to do with tfs, apart that sitting in the same port, and making it inaccessible.

Comment: Ah! Sounds like an Apache installed via the StackBuilder from the EnterpriseDB One Click installer. Not really "Apache EnterpriseDB" but I can kind of see where you got that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you must've installed PostgreSQL using the one-click installer for Windows, then ran the StackBuilder and installed Apache using StackBuilder.

If so, it's just an ordinary Apache install that you can configure just like normal. You need to either stop and disable any running Apache service in the Services control panel (`services.msc`).

Alternately, if you wish to continue using it but on a different port, edit the Apache configuration to set the `Listen` directive to something other than `8080` and change any `NameVirtualHost` and `VirtualHost` directives to use the new port, eg:

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ... blah blah ...
</VirtualHost>
```

would become:

```
Listen 8181
NameVirtualHost *:8181
<VirtualHost *:8181>
  ... blah blah ...
</VirtualHost>
```

See:

- [Apache - Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)
- [Apache - `Listen`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen)

You can find the location of the Apache config file by examining the command that's being used to run Apache. That might be a batch file to start it and stop it, or a service command in the services control panel. It'll probably be called `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`..

Comment: I have stopped all other in services, but did not solve it. I am reinstalling. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are 'proper' addresses, but unless the person trying to open the webpage has a valid TFS account then you will not be able to access TFS through the website.

Can you access: `http://localhost:8080/tfs/web`?

Is your Windows login allowed to access TFS server?

As Craig mentioned, you don't hive any information that could help diagnose what you're trying to achieve.  Why are you trying to access TFS through its web endpoints?  Did you make sure MSSQL and IIS are installed on the machine?  Why have you got apache and postgresql installed on a ALM server that doesn't require them?

TFS is a very complex product, and even though the development team has made huge strides in making it easy to install, it's no small task to get a server working.

Comment: I aim to access it with vs 2012 and vs 2008, to have an online repository for code.
I have mssql installed, updated, and configured. I have istalled the tfs successfully. I can access the tfs administration console, I can create collections, see them as online and such, in the manager.
If I try to see "Group Membership", I get the following error:"TF31002 Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server localhost:8080/tfs ..."
If i try to access the said urls in a browser, I also get 404.
I can also not access http://localhost:8080/tfs/web .